# Multiple fonts in a numbered section heading with XeLaTeX and Hyperref

Tags: sectioning, xetex, hyperref, fontspec

I'm trying to use `XeLaTeX` to build my document. I define sections containing two different fonts within the `section` command. I've managed to get this to work, but only when using the `*` version to remove numerals. If `hyperref` is included, then the regular version of the command fails.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily\fontTNR{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\fontAN{Arial}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\fontA}{\fontTNR\fontsize{16}{19.2}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\fontB}{\fontAN\fontsize{16}{19.2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section*{\fontA{Text1} \fontB{Text2}}

\end{document}
```

This passes through just fine. However, the following version with the `*` removed fails due to conflicts with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily\fontTNR{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\fontAN{Arial}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\fontA}{\fontTNR\fontsize{16}{19.2}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\fontB}{\fontAN\fontsize{16}{19.2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\section{\fontA{Text1} \fontB{Text2}}

\end{document}
```

I've tried looking into the `hyperref` file to trace the error but it is honestly far beyond my comprehension at this time. Here is the error I get from the log.

[image: Example of the error list, captured from TeXStudio.]

I'm assuming this has something to do with the way `hyperref` manages indices. Perhaps when `section*` is used this conflict is removed when the section is stripped from the table of contents?

I did look into using `titlesec` as a method of doing this task but failed to see how I could apply multiple fonts to the content with just a format specification.

Comment: you don't want the fonts in the table of contents anyway, so simply use `\section[Text1 Text2]{\fontA{Text1} \fontB{Text2}}`, then hyperref can use the version without fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wasn't aware of that capability but that does seem to work as a valid workaround. It is fair to call this a workaround? I would suppose that is bypassing the parsing issues within ``hyperref``?